# Template Xcode create several files both

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, templates

I want to make a xcode template to create several files at the same time, but I didn´t find anything of this. ¿Can you Help me?

Comment: Have you seen this link? https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates

Comment: Thanks David! I want to create all in different groups, how should I do?